# Add values together in for loop (Python)

Tags: python

```
word   = input('Enter word: ')
SCORES = {
  'a' : 1, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 3 , 'd' : 2, 'e' : 1, 'f' : 4, 'g' : 2,
  'h' : 4, 'i' : 1, 'j' : 8 , 'k' : 5, 'l' : 1, 'm' : 3, 'n' : 1,
  'o' : 1, 'p' : 3, 'q' : 10, 'r' : 1, 's' : 1, 't' : 1, 'u' : 1,
  'v' : 4, 'w' : 4, 'x' : 8 , 'y' : 4, 'z' : 10,
}

for letter in word:
  result = SCORES[letter]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Enter word: quiz
10
1
1
10
```

I want it so that I can add the values together to get 22. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it's the idiomatic solution:

```
sum(SCORES[letter] for letter in word)
```

In Python, *whenever possible* we prefer to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and/or [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of explicit looping. They're shorter, simpler and generally faster than explicit loops!

Comment: might be shorter and faster but not everything can be done in a list comprehension or generator expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
result = 0 # create variable outside the loop
for letter in word:   
   result += SCORES[letter] # add score for each letter 
print(result)   # print total
```